# Do I have to use the knockout with binding?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm fairly new to knockout and trying to understand how some of the bindings should work.

I thought that I could reference a child observable in a normal binding without the need for with but I cannot get it working.

My model and view model are;

```
        Model = function(name) {
            this.name = ko.observable(name);
        };

        ViewModel = function () {


            var list = ko.observableArray([new Model("Apple"), new Model("Pear")]),
                selectedItem = ko.observable();

            function selectItem(item) {
                selectedItem(item);
            }

            return {
                list: list,
                selectedItem: selectedItem,
                selectItem: selectItem
            };
        };
```

and here are the bindings:

```
        <div id="content">
        <ul id="list" data-bind="foreach: list">
            <li data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.selectItem"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p>Will show selected item</p>
    <div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Won't show selected item</p>
        <span data-bind="text: selectedItem().name()"></span>
    </div>
```

Alternatively a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathan_g/d9HEG/2/) is here.

As far as I understood I should be able to see a value for `selectedItem().name` but the apply bindings is throwing an error, however it works perfectly if the div has the `with: selectedItem` binding.

Do I have no optin but to use the `with` binding in this type of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with` bending beside setting the binding context also handles the case when the value is `null` or `undefinied`.

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)

> If the expression you supply evaluates to `null` or `undefined` **descendant elements will not be bound at all**, but will instead be removed from the document.

If you don't want to use the `with` you have to handle the `null` or `undefinied` case "by hand " so you can only call `name()` if the `selectedItem()` returned something.

This can be done with the statement `selectedItem() && selectedItem().name()`. (`null`, the empty string and `undefinied` evaluates to `false` evertying else is to `true`.)

So the following binding is working:

```
<span data-bind="text: selectedItem() && selectedItem().name()"></span>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ssp9y/)

Comment: Ah that makes sense because when the binding first happens there is no selected item. Many thanks.